# Reset form fields on text click

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a javascript event, which once clicked clear the values in the form.

I am building an online form, and if they user has already filled out the form. I have a message thats says not you (with the name they have entered) e.g not you harry, **click here.**

the click here part of the text will be clickable, and if the user clicks this then all the values within the form fields will be removed. in essence once clicked it will clear all the data on this webpage that is pulled from the form on the previous page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <base href="http://go.pardot.com" >
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta name="description" content=""/>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://go.pardot.com/l/190502/2018-02-22/7lvsrf/190502/46706/Favicon.jpg">
  <title>Medical Indemnity Initial Quote Form</title>
  
     <style> 
     
 form.form textarea.standard {
    height: 70px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 800px !important;
    float: none;
    /* border-radius: 5px; */
    border: none !Important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: white !important;
      }
          
form.form p span.description {
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 30px !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 1rem !important;
    width: 84% !important;
     }
     
#pardot-form input.text {
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 2em;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none ;
    color:white;
    border-bottom:1px solid #555555 !important;
    text-align:left !Important;
 margin-left:-57rem;  
  
 }
 
 @media (max-width: 791px) {
 #pardot-form input.text {
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 2em;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none ;
    color:white;
    border-bottom:1px solid #555555 !important;
    text-align:left !important; 
    margin-left: -22rem !important;
 }
}
 
@media (max-width: 1841px) {
 #pardot-form input.text {
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 2em;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 43px;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none ;
    color:white;
    border-bottom:1px solid #555555 !important;
    text-align:left !important; 
    margin-left: -18rem !important;
  }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 690px) and (min-width: 273px) {

 #pardot-form input.text {
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 2em;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none ;
    color:white;
    border-bottom:1px solid #555555 !important;
    text-align:left !important; 
    margin-left: -6rem !important;
  }
} 

form.form {
 text-align:center;
 }
 
 .container {
  background-color:#131313;
 }
 
form.form select {
   background-color:#131313;
   color:white;
   border:none;
   border-bottom:1px solid #555555 !important;
   width: 50%;
 }
 
form.form p label {
      color: #FFFFFF !important;
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: 100;
      text-align:center !Important;
}

@media (max-width: 641px) { 
form.form p label {
    background: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-size: 10px !important;
 }
}


form.form p.required label, form.form span.required label {
    background-position: top left;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

form.form p.required label, form.form span.required label {
   background-position: -9999px -9999px !important;
   text-align:left !important;
}

form.form input.date {
    background-color:#131313 !important;
    color:white !important;
    border:none !important;
    border-bottom:1px solid #555555 !important;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align:center;
    
}

form.form p.submit input { 
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #e93b00;
    width: auto;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 5px 20px 0 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    max-width: 610px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border:none;
}

@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 995px) {
form.form p.submit input { 
 display: inline-block;
    cursor: default;
 color:white !Important;
    background-color: #e93b00;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 5px 20px 0 20px;
    font-size: 70px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    max-width: 610px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 1rem !important;
    margin-bottom: 1rem !important;
}
}


@media (max-width: 800px)  { 
form.form p.required, form.form span.required, form.form label.required { 
   margin-top:2rem !Important;
   }
   }
   
form.form p.submit {
    margin: 0rem !important;
    padding: 0;
}

form.form .value span {
    display:inline-block !Important;
      border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: grey;
    display: inline-grid;
    opacity: 0.50 !important;
}

form.form .pd-radio .value span  {
    display:inline-block !important;
}

form.form p.required, form.form span.required, form.form label.required {
    font-weight: bold;
   
}

.select {
  font-size:30px;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:3px solid;
}

form.form p.required, form.form span.required, form.form label.required {
    margin-top:10rem;
}
 @media (max-width: 420px) {
form.form p.required, form.form span.required, form.form label.required {
margin-top:2rem !important; 
 }
}

form.form p label {
    display: block;
    float: none !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 13px 0 0;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100% !important;
}

a { 
    color:;#e93b00 !important;
}
a:visited { text-decoration: none; color:#e93b00 !important; }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; color:#e93b00 !important; }
a:focus { text-decoration: none; color:#e93b00 !important; }
a:hover, a:active { text-decoration: none; color:#e93b00 !important; }


.red-color, form.form p.error, form.form span.error, form.form div.error, form.form p.error label {
    color: #8b0000;
    font-size: 20px !Important;
    margin:0 !important; 
}
form.form span.value {
    display: block;
    margin-left:0 Important;
   
}

form.form .value span {
    margin-left:4rem;
       border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: grey;
    display: inline-grid;
    opacity: 0.50 !important;
}


@media (max-width: 1200px)  {
form.form .value span {
     margin-left:0rem !important;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: grey;
    display: inline-grid;
    opacity: 0.50 !important;
    /* width: 43%; */
    margin-top: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
 margin-left:0rem !Important;
 margin-right:0rem !important;
}
}



p.form-field.Marketing_Preferences.pd-checkbox.required.required-custom.error {
   
    margin-left: 0rem !important;
}

p.form-field.Marketing_Preferences.pd-checkbox.required.required-custom.error {
    
    margin-left: 0rem !important;
}

 #pardot-form span.error {
clear: left;
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: 2px;
padding-left: 166px;
}

input[type="checkbox" i] {
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 4px;
    float: right;
 height: 53px;
    width: 56px;
 
}

form.form p.required label, form.form span.required label {
 margin-left:0.5rem !important;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
span.value {
 width:100% !important;
 } 
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 300px)  {
form.form span.value {
 display:grid !important; 
 margin-left:0rem !important;
}
}

form.form span.value {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 0px !Important;
}

form.form p span.description {
    form.form p span.description {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 49px !important;
    font-size: 36px !important;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}
}

#boxes {
 margin-top:1rem !important;
 font-size:39px;
}

@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 995px) {
#boxes {
 color: white !important; 
 font-size:43px !Important;
 }
}

</style>
 

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://go.pardot.com/css/form.css?ver=20121030" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://go.pardot.com/js/piUtils.js?ver=20130530"></script><script type="text/javascript">
piAId = '191502';
piCId = '9424';
piHostname = 'pi.pardot.com';
if(!window['pi']) { window['pi'] = {}; } pi = window['pi']; if(!pi['tracker']) { pi['tracker'] = {}; } pi.tracker.pi_form = true;
(function() {
 function async_load(){
  var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://pi' : 'http://cdn') + '.pardot.com/pd.js';
  var c = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; c.parentNode.insertBefore(s, c);
 }
 if(window.attachEvent) { window.attachEvent('onload', async_load); }
 else { window.addEventListener('load', async_load, false); }
})();
</script></head>


 

 <body>
 <div class="container">
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="file:///C:/Users/HarryMead/Desktop/New%20folder/Document1.html" class="form" id="pardot-form">

<style type="text/css">
form.form p label { color: #000000; }
form.form p.required label, form.form span.required label { background: none; padding-left: 0px; line-height:1.4; margin-bottom:1rem; }
</style>





 
  
  
  
   
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="form-field  first_name pd-text required required-custom    ">
  <label class="field-label" for="190502_34068pi_190502_34068">Please enter your first name so I can start your quote... *</label>
  <input type="text" name="190502_34068pi_190502_34068" id="190502_34068pi_190502_34068" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="40" onchange="" />
</p>
<div id="error_for_190502_34068pi_190502_34068" style="display:none"></div>


<p class="form-field  last_name pd-text required required-custom    ">
  <label class="field-label" for="190502_34070pi_190502_34070">Thank you, please could you let me know your last name... *</label>
  <input type="text" name="190502_34070pi_190502_34070" id="190502_34070pi_190502_34070" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="80" onchange="" />
</p>
<div id="error_for_190502_34070pi_190502_34070" style="display:none"></div>


<p class="form-field  email pd-text required required-custom    ">
  <label class="field-label" for="190502_34072pi_190502_34072">Awesome! Please could you provide me your email address so that I can send your quote documents to you... *</label>
  <input type="text" name="190502_34072pi_190502_34072" id="190502_34072pi_190502_34072" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="255" onchange="piAjax.auditEmailField(this, 190502, 34072, 162304018);" /><br/><span class="description"> <a target="_self" href="file:///C:/Users/HarryMead/Desktop/New%20folder/Documenterror.html">Click Here</a>.</span>
</p>
<div id="error_for_190502_34072pi_190502_34072" style="display:none"></div>


<p class="form-field  phone pd-text required required-custom    ">
  <label class="field-label" for="190502_34074pi_190502_34074">Do you have a contact number? *</label>
  <input type="text" name="190502_34074pi_190502_34074" id="190502_34074pi_190502_34074" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="40" onchange="" />
</p>
<div id="error_for_190502_34074pi_190502_34074" style="display:none"></div>


<p class="form-field  company pd-text required required-custom    ">
  <label class="field-label" for="190502_34076pi_190502_34076">Thank you! And what is your business name? If you trade in your own name then that's fine - simply enter your full name *</label>
  <input type="text" name="190502_34076pi_190502_34076" id="190502_34076pi_190502_34076" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="255" onchange="" />
</p>
<div id="error_for_190502_34076pi_190502_34076" style="display:none"></div>


<p class="form-field  Marketing_Preferences pd-checkbox required required-custom">
  <label class="field=label" for="190502_34174pi_190502_34174">Occasionally we may wish to contact you to let you know about special offers and products we think may be of interest to you. We will never share your details with other third parties. Please tick if you are happy for us to contact you via the following:</label>
   <span class="value"><span><input type="checkbox" name="190502_34174pi_190502_34174_287262" id="190502_34174pi_190502_34174_287262" value="287262" onchange="" /><label class="inline" for="190502_34174pi_190502_34174_287262" id='boxes'>Email</label></span><span><input type="checkbox" name="190502_34174pi_190502_34174_287264" id="190502_34174pi_190502_34174_287264" value="287264" onchange="" /><label class="inline" for="190502_34174pi_190502_34174_287264"  id='boxes'>Phone</label></span><span><input type="checkbox" name="190502_34174pi_190502_34174_287266" id="190502_34174pi_190502_34174_287266" value="287266" onchange="" /><label class="inline" for="190502_34174pi_190502_34174_287266"  id='boxes'>Text</label></span><span><input type="checkbox" name="190502_34174pi_190502_34174_287268" id="190502_34174pi_190502_34174_287268" value="287268" onchange="" /><label class="inline" for="190502_34174pi_190502_34174_287268"  id='boxes'>None</label></span><span><input type="checkbox" name="190502_34174pi_190502_34174_287270" id="190502_34174pi_190502_34174_287270" value="287270" onchange="" /><label class="inline" for="190502_34174pi_190502_34174_287270"  id='boxes'>All</label></span></span>
</p>
<div id="error_for_190502_34174pi_190502_34174" style="display:none"></div>
   
  
  
  
 <p style="position:absolute; width:190px; left:-9999px; top: -9999px;visibility:hidden;">
  <label for="pi_extra_field">Comments</label>
  <input type="text" name="pi_extra_field" id="pi_extra_field"/>
 </p>
  
  
  <!-- forces IE5-8 to correctly submit UTF8 content  -->
  <input name="_utf8" type="hidden" value="&#9731;" />
  
  <p class="submit">
   <input type="submit" accesskey="s" value="Next" />
  </p>
 
 


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

 var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
 for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++) {
  var anchor = anchors[i];
  if(anchor.getAttribute("href")&&!anchor.getAttribute("target")) {
   anchor.target = "_top";
  }
 }
  
//]]>
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenDependentFields" id="hiddenDependentFields" value="" /></form>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(){ pardot.$(document).ready(function(){ (function() {
 var $ = window.pardot.$;
 window.pardot.FormDependencyMap = [];

 $('.form-field-master input, .form-field-master select').each(function(index, input) {
  $(input).on('change', window.piAjax.checkForDependentField);
  window.piAjax.checkForDependentField.call(input);
 });
})(); });})();</script>
<script> 
var $inputs = $("input");       // get all inputs first

$inputs.keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var index = $inputs.index(this) + 1;  // get next index of input
    if (index < $inputs.length) {         // check if not last input
      $inputs.eq(index).get(0).focus();   // focus next
    }
  }
});
</script>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/32hesfre/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the `reset()` function for the link?

```
<a href="#" onclick='document.getElementById("pardot-form").reset();'>Click Here</a>
```

Working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/32hesfre/6/

OR, add a reset button inside the form tags:

```
<input type="reset" value="Click here"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a "out of the box" feature in Pardot - see screen grab[image].